# using jQuery to send ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

so im trying to get jquery to send an ajax call to update the comments database. i cant seem to find whats wrong with the code. been on the internets all day trying to find out.

```
<div class="comment">
<textarea name="comment" onkeydown="test(event)"></textarea>
</textarea>
</div>

    function test(event) {
    if (event.keyCode==13) {
         var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "commentupdate.php",
          data: "comment=" + comment,
        });
        $('.comment').hide();
        $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
    }
}
```

commentupdate.php

```
include('MasterHub_DBCon.php');
$COOKIEINFO = $_COOKIE['masterhub_user']; $USERCOOKIEINFO = explode('+', $COOKIEINFO); 
$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `dmech_main`.`COMMENTS` (`ID`, `USERNAME`, `COMMENT`, `COMMENTID`) VALUES (NULL, \'' .             $COOKIEINFO['0'] . '\', \'' . $comment . '\', \'' . $_SESSION['COMMENTID'] . '\');";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Could you post the code for commentupdate.php, so we know what it's expecting?

Comment: so is commentupdate.php hit? or hit with no comment? or ...?

Comment: posting commentupdate.php above. i tried to put an echo in the php page to see if it went to the page, but it didnt

Comment: A couple of suggestions.  First, since your PHP page is altering the database, this should be a POST rather than a GET.  A GET should never alter the state of the system.  Second, you need a more suitable tool to debug your AJAX traffic, such as Firebug or Fiddler.

Comment: ok thank you, i have switched to POST, but now when i enter the screen freezes till i leave the tab

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `val()` I guess. Try -

```
var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]').val();
```

Instead of -

```
var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting the javascript inside of a

```
<script>
```

tag to begin with.

Comment: of course i did that, i was trying to give as little frivilous information as possible

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to encode the data yourself and pass a string, or pass object:

## 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript>

function test(event) {
   if (event.keyCode==13) {
      var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "commentupdate.php",
         data: "comment=" + encodeURIComponent(comment)
         });
      $('.comment').hide();
      $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
   }
}

</script>
```

## 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript>

function test(event) {
   if (event.keyCode==13) {
      var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "commentupdate.php",
         data: { comment: comment }
         });
      $('.comment').hide();
      $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
   }
}

</script>
```

Quote from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ :

> **data**
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Comment: when i use data: { comment: comment} it totally freezes my screen till i exit the tab

Comment: do you get any errors when this happens? (check javascript console)

Comment: by the way, if it's GET request anyway, then you can construct the url yourself, too... "commentupdate.php?comment=" + encodeURIComponent(comment)

Comment: no i dont get anything, it just bogs out till im forced to close it

Comment: is it possible that it does reach the server, but the script takes a long time to respond? Also, as a side note, your php script (the code pasted above) allows sql injections...

Comment: i took out everything in the php file, and just put an echo in there, and it still bogged out

Comment: As Dan already suggested above, try using firebug (or some other tool you like for debugging the requests)... in firebug the Net tab saves a lot of otherwise gray hair ;)